# Crontab for php

Tags: php

I explain my problem.
I created a file named newsletter.php that contains this code:

```
$mytime = $db->fetchOne("SELECT CURTIME()"); //$db is a connection with config.php

$dataattuale  = time();
$b_dataatuale = date('G', $dataattuale);

echo($mytime);

if (($mytime > "12:49:00") && ($mytime < "12:51:00")) { // funzione orario

    // This query is used to extract email the Admin.
    $thread_qry10 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = '1' LIMIT 1";

    $row10 = XenForo_Application::get('db')->fetchAll($thread_qry10);

    foreach ($row10 AS $rows10) {
        $mailemail = $rows10['email'];
    }

    //This query is used to extract emails from those who have chosen to receive

    $thread_qry11 = "
        SELECT email
        FROM user AS u JOIN user_field_value AS uf ON u.user_id = uf.user_id
        WHERE
            uf.field_value  = '1'
            AND uf.field_id = 'xDNewsletter'
    ";

    $row11 = XenForo_Application::get('db')->fetchAll($thread_qry11);

    foreach ($row11 AS $rows11) {
        $mailuseremail .= $rows11['email'] . ',';
    }

    $urlRefresh = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $UrlActive . 'index.php?pages/Digest/';

    //Open file log for write
    $log = fopen("../" . $UrlActive . "xenDigest/crontab.txt", "w") or die ("Impossible create the file.");
    // write the current date on the log file
    $scrivi = fwrite($log, "43 13 * * * /usr/bin/lynx " . $urlRefresh);
    #close the file
    fclose($log);
}
```

As you can see before I check if the current time of the server is more or less hours chosen by me, after I write the file in txt format called crontab.txt.

But all this does not work. I wanted to know why?

The txt file is written is written, and I've tried is to write:

//link to the page

```
43 13 * * * /usr/bin/lynx http://demo.netkingz.it/xenforo/index.php?pages/Digest/
```

is to write:

//Link to the file .php

```
 43 13 * * * /usr/bin/lynx http://demo.netkingz.it/xenforo/library/xD/Listener/xDDay.php
```

but don't works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is this in your user crontab or the server crontab in /etc/crontab ?
If the server's, you need to specify the user like this:

```
43 13 * * * root /usr/bin/lynx http://demo.netkingz.it/xenforo/library/xD/Listener/xDDay.php
```

Comment: this code is on FTP no in the server. I have to upload it to the server? how do you? but root is the username of user?

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I understood your question but I am confused and don't know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I submit the problem.
I'm using a forum system which implies that the development of external mod with attached files to be included in the "library" and is created for each mod to a specific folder that contains the code.
The purpose of my code is to send the email, then a system of Newsletter.
I'll post the code below in the php file that is called DigestDay.php and that is in the path library / Digest / Listener / DigestDay.php, even now I announce that the file permissions are at 755, here is the php code :

```
<?php
```

class Digest_Listener_DigestDay
{

public static function includeMyDigestDay($hookName, &$contents, array $hookParams, XenForo_Template_Abstract $template)
    {

```
  if($hookName == 'xDDay') {


        ob_start();
```

$db = XenForo_Application::getDb();

```
                    if ( !$db ) {


                        die( 'This script did not connect to the database' . mysql_error() );
                    }

                        $mytime = $db->fetchOne("SELECT CURTIME()");        

                    $dataattuale=time();
                    $b_dataatuale=date('G', $dataattuale);


                echo($mytime);

                    if($mytime > "01:00:00"){ // funzione orario




                        $thread_qry10 = "SELECT * FROM xf_user WHERE user_id = '1' LIMIT 1";

                                $row10 = XenForo_Application::get('db')->fetchAll($thread_qry10);

                                foreach ( $row10 AS $rows10 ) {
                                    $mailemail = $rows10['email'];


                                }



                                $thread_qry11 = "SELECT email FROM xf_user AS u JOIN xf_user_field_value AS uf ON u.user_id = uf.user_id WHERE uf.field_value = '1' AND uf.field_id = 'xDNewsletter'";

                                $row11 = XenForo_Application::get('db')->fetchAll($thread_qry11);

                                foreach ( $row11 AS $rows11 ) {
                                    $mailuseremail .= $rows11['email'].',';


                                }


                                                $urlMail = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

                                                // costruiamo alcune intestazioni generali
                                                $header = 'From: '.$mailemail;
                                                //$header .= "CC: Altro Ricevente <altroricevente@dominio.net>\n";
                                                $header .= "X-Mailer: ".$mailemail."\n";
                                                $headers = "BBC: ".$mailuseremail;

                                                // costruiamo le intestazioni specifiche per il formato HTML
                                                $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
                                                $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
                                                $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
                                                 $messaggio = "Prova invio messaggio";

                                                $subject = 'Newsletter from '.$urlMail ;

                                                    if( @mail($headers, $subject, $messaggio, $header) ) echo "";
                    else echo "";

                    }

                $urlRefresh = 'php /home/USER_NAME/public_html/demo/xenforo/library/Digest/Listener/DigestDay.php' ;


            # apertura in scrittura di un file di log
            $log = fopen("../".$UrlActive."Digest/crontab.txt","w") or die ("Impossible create the file.");
            # scrittura della data corrente sul file di log      
            $scrivi = fwrite($log,"33 01 * * * ".$urlRefresh);  
            #chiusura del file      
            fclose($log);        

            }

            $contents .= ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
        }




}
```

}

?>

What this code does, or rather should do is:
1 - Remove the current time from the database

```
 $mytime = $db->fetchOne("SELECT CURTIME()");
```

2 - Check that the current time is greater than 1:00

```
if($mytime > "01:00:00"){ // funzione orario
```

3 - And in case it has to send him an email (newsletter of course) from the selected emails from db

After this piece of code you should rewrite the file again cron job thanks to this code:

```
$urlRefresh = 'php /home/USER_NAME/public_html/demo/xenforo/library/Digest/Listener/DigestDay.php' ;


            # apertura in scrittura di un file di log
            $log = fopen("../".$UrlActive."Digest/crontab.txt","w") or die ("Impossible create the file.");
            # scrittura della data corrente sul file di log      
            $scrivi = fwrite($log,"33 01 * * * ".$urlRefresh);  
            #chiusura del file      
            fclose($log);
```

We get to the essence of the matter.
The system for which I am developing the mod provides a visual part obtained from the callback function, in fact if I do I access the page containing the above code, with access I send my input that obviously does send the newsletter properly, but I did not want or my future clients having to go to that page every time to make sure that newsletter being sent, use the cron job.
The codes of cron job also used via CPanel on hosting Netsons were the following:

```
37  01  *   *   *   php /home/NOME_DI_ACCESSO_UTENTE/public_html/demo/xenforo/library/Digest/Listener/DigestDay.php
```

this code above I have been instructed by Netsons same and in fact doing the checks the code seems to work, or better to say the response from the CPanel that tells me that the call to the above php file arrives it went well but obviously not the Newsletter are sent. The response that I get in the email response from CPanel is this: Content-type: text / html.

Then as I tried this code:

```
37   01 *   *   *   php -f -q /home/NOME_DI_ACCESSO_UTENTE/public_html/demo/xenforo/library/Digest/Listener/DigestDay.php
```

This code always on hand suggeritomi Netsons seems that sometimes functions in the sense that I've been waiting the arrival of the time indicated , and after 6 hours ( then at 7 o'clock in the morning compared to 1 and 37 at night) came the Newsletter , the fact is , however, that after a couple of days have stopped coming .
The answer he gave me was the CPanel : No input file specified .

I also tried to change the asterisks putting all * (****) but in addition to the response from the CPanel get me the email of the newsletter do not come, but if I go directly to the page instead depart , so this makes me think that is not a problem code but to call in your code .

I also tried to insert # / usr / bin / php first of all the php code posted above , but nothing .

For Netsons the code you gave me works , but for me does not make the call to the file because the file code if one is accessing the page containing the code sends the Newsletter .

I hope I have explained everything , I hope someone can help me out .
Sorry if I have to open another application segnalarmelo just that I do now.
Thank you.